# "How to Read an SDK" Update for PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, syntax, powershell-2.0

This is going to sound like a dumb question, but I was wondering where I could find the "Help" file on *how* to read PowerShell's Help files.  To illustrate, when I was first learning VBS, I came across [this Sesame Script article on "How to Read an SDK"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176976.aspx).  This was written when VBS was the prominent scripting language for system administration in a Windows environment, so there's no PowerShell examples.  I figured there would be a PowerShell equivalent by now, so I've been searching the MSDN/TechNet Library for the past couple weeks and haven't found anything.  I've read the [Windows PowerShell Owner's Manual](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee221100.aspx), but there was nothing on this specific topic in it nor any resources to which I should go to.  So, has anyone found it?  Does an update or equivalent even exist within Microsoft's official documentation?

Another reason I ask is because I found a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fTIwRJsupLI) that helped me accurately read the Help information that comes from the "Get-Help" cmdlet; there's nothing wrong with it, I like the video, but I was wondering where the helpful gentleman, or anybody else, could find the information?  It must exist, since he made a video about it, right?

Comment: @EBGreen: You've lost me with that "char[15]"...sorry, the best I can assume is a Carriage Return from the ASCII Table?  Well, as to the writing it myself?  I'm not an authority on PS (more like uber-noob), so I would be the last person to believe anything from, but I was wanting to see if there was something "official" from Microsoft; that's not to discredit those that aren't officially endorsed by Microsoft (like that linked video), I was just wondering if it's in the MSDN/TechNet Library and if I missed it?  Besides, if I wrote one, I doubt I could host it on the MSDN/TechNet Library, lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Windows PowerShell User's Guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc196356.aspx) has many sub-pages about how to use PowerShell. Use the navigation tree at the left to browse the different topics.

[This page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347689.aspx) in particular talks about how to get help for CmdLets and other topics.

To directly answer the question, the command you can use is this:

`Get-Help About_Command_Syntax`

Comment: Could you edit this in, please: `Get-Help About_Command_Syntax`.  To save you the hassle, I've edited it, but it won't show until peer-review.  Anyway, I found the command-string in the 2nd link you referenced.  It was fortunate they used that command-string as an example or else I probably would have been left searching for quite a bit longer ^^;